# Not able to load a pickle file cloning from others repo due to "UnpicklingError: invalid load key."

Tags: python, pickle

I try to load the pickle file from other people. I believe it is a neural network model created by `torch`. The variable is simply saved by `pickle.dump(variable, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`. However, I had a hard time to load it into my local machine. I don't want to retrain the model again since it's not efficient. Can anyone help me to load the pickle the file? I have tried to google it, but nothing of the solution can help me.

I try to load a pickle file created by others. I clone it from the repo on GitLab. The code is simply like:

```py
import pickle

with open('pickle_from_repo.pickle', 'rb') as f:
  var = pickle.load(f)
```

and the error I got is:

```
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
```

I have checked the source code, the variable is stored into pickle by

```
def dump(self, path):
  with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(self.classes_, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Some people told me it might be `git lfs` problem, but I don't quite understand why this will be the problem.

Comment: What is the exact issue you're facing? What have you tried? Provide some code samples. We can't help you if we don't know what your problem is.

Comment: just edit my question. hope this could give u more details.

Answer (score 5):

The error of loading pickles with was caused by the lack of full files. Due to their size, they are stored in a special part of GIT and must be downloaded in a special way.

Use LFS should help you solve the problem.

https://git-lfs.github.com/

```
> git lfs install
> git lfs fetch
> git lfs pull
```

Comment: This should work for you guys.